# Complex parameterisation of a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

In my Complex Analysis notes, the parameterisation of a circle of radius $r$ centred at the point $z_0$ in the complex plane is given by $$z(t) = z_0 +re^{it}$$

I cannot seem to see where this comes from? Can anyone please show me how they came to this parameterisation?

I know that a complex circle can be given by $$|z - z_0| = r$$ but I do not see where the above mentioned parameterisation comes from.

Comment: the first one is in polar coordinates!!

Comment: Do you know that $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, from $|z - z_0| = r$, you can get $z - z_0 = re^{i\theta}$

This follows because $e^{i\theta}$ is the general form of a complex number of magnitude $1$.

After you've done that, the required locus immediately follows.